# Fix for Border line not full length

Tags: html, css

The border line is leaving a bit of space. How can I make it the full length? There's a bit of space left at the edges where I apply border color, I need how to remove the spaces.

```css
#About-main blockquote{
    width: 70%;
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-left-color: green;
    border-right-color: white;
    border-top-color: white;
    border-bottom-color: white;
}
```

```html
<main id="About-main">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores hic blanditiis impedit fugiat earum dolor distinctio expedita harum ratione excepturi illo debitis voluptates dolorem non delectus, odit nostrum praesentium quis!</p>
            <blockquote>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod quis ipsum ea porro, quidem repudiandae doloribus ex consequatur, et neque laborum facilis delectus nihil amet facere odit error, architecto placeat.</blockquote>
        </main>
```

Comment: what do you mean by leaving a little space? It is full-length to me. Do you mean the cut corner edges?

Comment: Yes, the cut corner edges.

Comment: Then the linked duplicate is correct. Instead of using a `border` use a `box-shadow`: `box-shadow: -4px 0 0 0 green;`

Comment: Doing this works.